# How to use git with PhpStorm?

Tags: git, magento, phpstorm

I'm new to version control. I've recently started using PhpStorm and it's great, however I want to utilise git. I've got a private repo on BitBucket, but it's the logic I'm struggling to understand so would appreciate some guidance.

Presumably the idea of git is to allow collaboration as well as version control, meaning at any point, if used correctly, the "latest" version of a project should be available online, presumably in my private repo for example. Then allowed users/collaborators, can download, modify and then commit back to the repo. I think I understand that part.

So where does the "live" site come in, i.e. the site that exists on the web server that people access? How do we push from repo to here? I'm a little bit confused. I've had some advice that it's "best" to work on the site on a local stack, so I'm using MAMP. So I have to download the site from the web server, do an initial commit to BitBucket repo, then check files in/out from here? How do I complete the "circle" and push from repo to web server to "go live"?

It's possible I've got the wrong end of the stick, but I'm struggling to get my head round it at the moment. I've done the "try git" guide and read a couple of articles but perhaps it's just me but I don't really see how you complete the operation. Surely the end game is to have the site live and running on a web server accessible by people, not stuck in a repo somewhere waiting to be edited?

I'm using Magento for most of my projects so as you're aware this becomes pretty large pretty fast, so multiple rounds of uploading/downloading and moving would be a nightmare.

Any advice or simplified instructions or explanations as to how the process works would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your question, actually? Marking it as off-topic, read [faq], please.

Comment: See http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Surely the end game is to have the site live and running on a web server accessible by people, not stuck in a repo somewhere waiting to be edited?

Nope. That’s not what git is for. Git is a version control system, not anything related to a webserver. There are many ways to deploy the content of a git repository on a webserver, but git does not provide a real “build-in” or preferred method. The simplest way is:

1. install git on the webserver
2. clone the repository on the server
3. run `git pull` on the server whenever you want it to update to the current state.

Fore more solutions that do not require ssh access / are fully automated, google for “deploy git repo on webserver”